# Insert link source path file instead of an image as VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, image, hyperlink

I would like to modify this code so instead of inserting the image of a folder into excel given a condition, it should copy just the path link (as an hyperlink) and paste it to cell (instead of a picture like it's being done now) from its source folder. This would be solely to make the file less heavier.

Herwith the actual code:

```
Sub InserImage()
    Dim ficimg As Variant
    Dim derlig As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Ma_forme As Shape
    Dim Maplage As Range

    derlig = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'derlig = 10

    For i = 2 To derlig
        For Each Maplage In ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
            If Ma_forme Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                ficimg = "S:\Transversal projects\SAP Data\Articles\" & Range("A" & i) & "\" & Range("A" & i) & ".jpg"
                nom = Range("A" & i).Value

                With ActiveSheet
                    .Shapes.AddPicture ficimg, True, True, Left:=Range("B" & i).Left, Top:=Range("B" & i).Top, Height:=Range("B" & i).Height, Width:=Range("B" & i).Width
                End With
            End If
        Next Maplage
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try to solve it? Did you have a look at the [Hyperlinks.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlinks-add-method-excel)? What is your question? Please understand that this is not a free coding service.

Comment: Also don't use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This just hides errors but they still occur, you just cannot see them. A code with that line cannot really be debugged. Remove it or replace it with a proper error handling.

Comment: I know it's not a free coding service but I'm trying to properly code on VBA.

Yes I've checked Hyperlinks.Add.Method but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

My question is; right now this code is inserting an image based on a folder named "P00063", which inside contains the photo of that same part also named as "P00063.jpg". What I want is that instead of inserting the photo, it should insert the file path to that picture (in regards to the corresponding cell that has the name "P00063": "S:\Transversal projects\SAP\Data\Articles\P00063\P00063.jpg"

Comment: So if you want this as a text only just write something like `Range("B" & i) = ficimg` instead of the picture add or if you want the path to be clickable use the Hyperlinks method I linked above.

Comment: Much appreciated PEH. I made it work thanks to your suggestions.

Comment: Adding one more comment. With which method could I tell VBA that a folder doesn't exist yet? Because right now on the cell it's showing a file path link but still it doesn't exists and you notice that until you click on it and you get an error. (The main thing behind all this it's that I want to know which spare part still doesn't have photo). I tried that once by inserting a pic but I couldn't link the image with the cell, now I've found the solution of inserting the link but this problem raised.

Comment: The following returns `0` if a folder doesn't exist `len(dir("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\tt", vbDirectory))`